# How can I know bluetooth is enabled or not on Windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I can use ConnectionSettingsTask to access Bluetooth settings, but how can I know whether Bluetooth's enabled after the task is completed?

I checked windows phone marketplace, found that some app can do that, for example:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quick-settings/2a2cbaa7-6d75-420c-ae14-2339618da43e

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a suggestion,this is what i am using, i am sure that there are better ways

```
 private async void FindPaired()
    {
        Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder.Start();
        try
        {
            var peers = await Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
            bth = true; //boolean variable
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x8007048F)
            {
                bth = false;
            }
           
        }          
    }
```

An error `0x8007048F` indicated if Bluetooth is turned off. This is working for me without any problems. For more information [visit this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Good luck mate (:

Comment: @See Sharp I tried the same code above. But even i turned on the bluetooth will go to the catch block. I don't know why?

Comment: @See Sharp Check out this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296898/how-could-i-enable-bluetooth-in-windows-phone-8-after-checking-disbale-of-blueto)

Comment: The original question asks how to check if BT is enabled or not. This is exactly what I need. But the answers only discuss if a BT device is connected or not. But "connected/disconnected" and "enabled/disabled" are two different things ...