# How could i enable bluetooth in Windows phone 8 After Checking Disbale of Bluetooth

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth

i want to check whether bluetooth is enabled or not.
If bluetooth is not enabled means i will ask one popup says(Allow the bluetooth to on (yes/no)) Based one the response I need to proceed.

If user pressed Yes means how could i enabled bluetooth in windows phone 8 device.
without redirecting to the bluetooth page.

I tried looking this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895884/how-can-i-know-bluetooth-is-enabled-or-not-on-windows-phone-8)

Comment: sorry, but you cannot change the settings through code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly enable Bluetooth from code, but instead, you can bring the user to the Bluetooth setting page by using `ConnectionSettingsTask` launcher:

```cs
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.Bluetooth;
connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

See: [How to use the connection settings task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394011%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

More about Launchers and Choosers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769542%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

The Bluetooth settings page can also be launches using a URI scheme:

```cs
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-bluetooth:"));
```

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: & See Sharp 
Is that possible to find the Bluetooth Name & Address of Windows Phone 8.?

Comment: Have a look at Proximity and PeerFinder classes