# Windows phone 8.1 Bluetooth on/off change

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How to handle bluetooth on/off change in Windows phone 8.1. Is there any event for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the [TriggeredConnectionStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.triggeredconnectionstatechanged) event (in `Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder`).

The event gives you a state back that is of type [triggeredconnectstate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.triggeredconnectstate) which can be `canceled` or `failed`.

Comment: Event is not firing according to bluetooth on/off

Comment: Do you have an open connection or "just" want to know when it goes from on to off and vice versa?

Comment: I want to know the phone bluetooth state on to off and vice versa.

Comment: Then I think you're toast, there is no event that I know of. You could long pool the service by trying to connect to it regularly as is done in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895884/how-can-i-know-bluetooth-is-enabled-or-not-on-windows-phone-8 but it is pretty dirty and and could have massive negative effects on the battery.